# I am unable to handle the application life cycle event of kubernets from my .net core consol Application

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, console-application

I am trying to handle prestop event of kuberenetes on my application but I didn't receive any events on my .net core console application

```
lifecycle:
      postStart:
        tcpSocket:
          port: 13000
      preStop:
        tcpSocket:
          port: 13001
```

I am receiving on event log

> FailedPreStopHook   pod/podname-795764db56-9q9pg    Cannot run
> handler: invalid handler:
> &LifecycleHandler{Exec:nil,HTTPGet:nil,TCPSocket:&TCPSocketAction{Port:{0
> 13001 },Host:,},}

I have tried another solution to start working with native functions like

```
[DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler handler, bool add);
```

But I am able only to run it on windows environment but once I go to linux container I receive error

> Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load
> shared library 'Kernel32' or one of its dependencies. In order to help
> diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment
> variable: libKernel32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory

Please advice if there is any other solution to this issue to handle closing greacefully for consol application on linux contianer environment.

Answer (score 0):

`ConsoleCtrlEventHandler` is only available under windows. You should use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.PosixSignalRegistration` in a Linux container and under Windows:

```cs
var isCancelRequested = false;
var signal = "none";
using (var protectSIGINTfromGC = PosixSignalRegistration.Create(PosixSignal.SIGINT, (signalContext) =>
{
    signal = "SIGINT";
    signalContext.Cancel = true;
    isCancelRequested = true;
}))
{
    /* Inovke your Root command handler here */
}
```

You have to protect the event handler from being collected by the garbage collector, see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74460515/3303008).

PosixSignalRegistration was introduced with .NET core 6.0.
For older versions, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` is availavle and is raised on **SIGTERM** and `Console.CancelKeyPress` is raised on **SIGINT**.

`PosixSignalRegistration` can cancel **SIGTERM** so you can clean up *outside* the event handler. With `ProcessExit` you have to can clean up *inside* the event handler:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Process ID = {Environment.ProcessId}");
    var cancel = false;
    Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler((s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"CancelKeyPress");
        e.Cancel = true; // not terminate immediately
        cancel = true;
    });
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler((s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ProcessExit");
        Console.WriteLine($"Process {Environment.ProcessId} exited gracefully (SIGTERM).");
    });
    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    } while (!cancel);
    Console.WriteLine($"Process {Environment.ProcessId} exited gracefully (SIGINT).");
}
```

The results:

```bash
$ dotnet run &
Process ID = 4113
$ kill -s INT 4113
CancelKeyPress
Process 4113 exited gracefully (SIGINT).
$ dotnet run &
Process ID = 4395
$ kill -s TERM 4395
ProcessExit
Process 4395 exited gracefully (SIGTERM).
```